# How can I implement IConvertible object in my code?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid, ado.net, iconvertible

When I finished inputting all the data in the datagrid columns
upon clicking the save button this error returns:

ERROR:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in system.data.dll

Additional information: Object must implement IConvertible.

```
 Dim sqlsyntax As String
    sqlsyntax = "INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_ID, OE_Category,OE_SubCategory, OE_Name, OE_User, OE_Brand, OE_Model, OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo, OE_PropertyNo, OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus, OE_Status, OE_Dept_Code,OE_Location_Code,OE_Remarks)" _
             & "VALUES(@OE_ID,@OE_Category,@OE_SubCategory,@OE_Name,@OE_User,@OE_Brand,@OE_Model,@OE_Specs,@OE_SerialNo,@OE_PropertyNo,@OE_Static_IP,@OE_Vendor,@OE_PurchaseDate,@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear,@OE_WarrantyStatus,@OE_Status,@OE_Dept_Code,@OE_Location_Code,@OE_Remarks)"

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlsyntax, sqlconn)

    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", SqlDbType.Char)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", SqlDbType.Char)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", SqlDbType.Int)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", SqlDbType.Char)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", SqlDbType.Char)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", SqlDbType.Char)
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar)


    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGrid1.VisibleRowCount - 1

        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = DataGrid1(i, 0).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(1).Value = DataGrid1(i, 1).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(2).Value = DataGrid1(i, 2).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(3).Value = DataGrid1(i, 3).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(4).Value = DataGrid1(i, 4).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(5).Value = DataGrid1(i, 5).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(6).Value = DataGrid1(i, 6).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(7).Value = DataGrid1(i, 7).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(8).Value = DataGrid1(i, 8).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(9).Value = DataGrid1(i, 9).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(10).Value = DataGrid1(i, 10).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(11).Value = DataGrid1(i, 11).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(12).Value = DataGrid1(i, 12).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(13).Value = DataGrid1(i, 13).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(14).Value = DataGrid1(i, 14).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(15).Value = DataGrid1(i, 15).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(16).Value = DataGrid1(i, 16).GetType
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(17).Value = DataGrid1(i, 17).GetType
        sqlconn.Open()

        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("success fully added")
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Clear()

    Next
    sqlconn.Close()
```

How do I implement IConvertible in an object?

Comment: Have a look here please http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx

Comment: Do you think you have to post _all_ of that code in order to get an answer? Which line produced the exception? In fact, you clearly have no idea what you're doing. You don't want to be setting the parameter to a type. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohnSaunders is right. You keep posting about this piece of code since yesterday asking for help about the most basic stuff. But that would be fine, if at least you would accept some of the answers put forward for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I really do not understand why you keep assigning a type to the value of the parameter...

Surely, what you want is casting the content of your cell to the right type, for example in your first line you would want to do:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = CStr(DataGrid1(i, 0))
```

Or possibly

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = DataGrid1(i, 0).ToString()
```

For any parameter of type `Char`.
For `DateTime` or `Int` type parameters you would want to use `CDate()` and `CInt`, but I don't think you want to use `GetType()` as that just gets the type of the value in the cell and not it's actual value.

Also, whilst you seem to have 19 parameters to your command, you are only adding 18 values to it, I don't know if that is desired behaviour, but it seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you want to insert a `Type` value into each parameter:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = DataGrid1(i, 0).GetType
```

The error is also most likely due to trying to convert a `Type` to the various data types the parameter is intended to hold.

Perhaps you intended to do the following instead:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = DataGrid1(i, 0).Value
```